# Controller not working in Internet Explorer only

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a SharePoint app which uses angular JS. All the required scripts (as per application requirement) and styles are added dynamically through script in sequential fashion.

HTML is created through scripts.

Everything is working fine in all browsers except IE. All of the data is loaded and functioning properly.

Controller JS:

```
var app = angular.module("scaInfoApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("scaInfoCtrl", function ($scope,CRUDService) {
    console.log('Controller Loaded');
    $scope.vm = this;
    $scope.vm.data = {};
    $scope.vm.data.mu = [];
    $scope.vm.getPresence = getPresence;
    console.log('Controller Loaded');

    var promise = CRUDService.GetUserProfileListItems("$filter=IsSiteAdmin eq 1", "");
    promise.then(function (data) {
        angular.forEach(data.results, function (siteAdmin) {
            console.log('controller for each');
            $scope.vm.data.mu.push({ title: siteAdmin.Title, id: siteAdmin.Id });
        });
        if (!$scope.$$phase) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    }, function (status) {
        console.log("Error " + status);
    });

    function getPresence(userId, userTitle) {
        if (userId && userTitle) {
            return '<span class="ms-noWrap"><span class="ms-spimn-presenceLink"><span class="ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-imnImg ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10"><img class="ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-online-10x10x32" src="' + appweburl + '/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23"  alt="" /></span></span><span class="ms-noWrap ms-imnSpan"><span class="ms-spimn-presenceLink"><img class="ms-hide" src="' + appweburl + '/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23"  alt="" /></span><a class="ms-subtleLink" target="_parent"  onclick="GoToLinkOrDialogNewWindow(this);return false;" href="' + appweburl + '/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=' + userId + '">' + userTitle + '</a></span></span>';
        }
        return '<span></span>';
    }
});
```

Related HTML CODE:

```
function createSiteAdminSection() {
    $('<div/>', { id: 'scaInfoApp', 'class': 'container', 'data-ng-app': 'scaInfoApp', 'data-ng-controller': 'scaInfoCtrl' }).html('<div id="userBind" class="row"></div>').appendTo('#modal2 .modal-body');
    $('<ul/>', { 'class': 'list-users', }).html('<li data-ng-repeat="r in vm.data.mu track by $index"><span data-ng-bind-html="vm.getPresence(r.id, r.title)"></span></li>').appendTo('#userBind');

}
```

Again, this whole application is working fine on Chrome, Mozilla, Safari but not in Internet Explorer.

Thanks,

Comment: explorer version & angular version ?

Comment: what does the console of IE say?

Comment: It has been awhile, but as I remember correctly IE will have issues running code using the `console` object until you open the developer tools because IE never creates it until the tools are open.  Hit F12 or comment the `console.log` lines and try it again.

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst There are no such errors on console related to these scripts, errors are related to some SharePoint JS on IE.
Also, if debug using breakpoints then code in IE, it works perfectly and render data.

CHROME LOGS:

Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function(anonymous function) @ msformbundle.js:1(anonymous function) @ msformbundle.js:1
App.js:32 Controller Loaded
App.js:37 Controller Loaded
customsettings.js:231 Custom Actions Provisioned
App.js:42 controller for each

Comment: @K.Toress IE11 and AngularJS v1.3.4 , but it is not working on any version of IE

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution of this issue.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['scaInfoApp']);
});
```

Bootstrap angular app in this way.